# Play a graph line about the time in javascript

Tags: javascript, rickshaw

I am discovering the amazing Rickshaw library !

There is one thing i am not sure i can do, i would like to "play" my graph line.

I mean, when i click a button, i would like to have like a vertical line (representing the current time), which go strait, the left part of the line would be a different color (representing the past) than the right part (representing the futur).

Is it possible to build this kind of thing (a graph that we can "play" about the time) wich Rickshaw?

If not, do you know a javascript library which enables that?